# Blank page during facebook authentication

Tags: android, authentication, facebook

I get blank page in facebook authentication:

http://i43.tinypic.com/2u9391d.png - like this

I am using facebook API and my authentication code:

```
public void facebookAuthorize(){
    myPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = myPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = myPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if(access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

    }
    if(expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    /*
     * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
     */
    if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access" }, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                editor.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }
}
```

How to solve it?

Comment: I presume that you are logging and can see that you are getting an onComplete? But without seeing your values, a possible reason (for what looks like a login error) is that your accesstoken is no longer valid. Try logging the accesstoken value and doing a login at the browser address bar (something like https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=touch&redirect_uri=fbconnect://success&type=user_agent&app_id=<your_app_id>&access_token=<your_access_token> - you can check the syntax in the SDK dialog() method)? Another is that you have a Facebook app running and are having issues with SSO?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your app signature on the facebook app page? 
[Facebook Android Tutorial Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you correctly added you application domain (not localhost) on the facebook app page?